# Pandas Data Frame Crosstab / Pivot Table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm writing a program that reads in a csv file and does some computations. I've been trying to use pandas data frames. For example, the following is how my data is structured.

```
  Sequence  ID  Hits
0     Seq1  K1     1
1     Seq1  K2     0
2     Seq2  K1     2
3     Seq2  K2     1
4     Seq3  K1     0
5     Seq3  K2     2
```

I want the data to end up looking something like this:

```
    Seq1  Seq2  Seq3
ID                  
K1     1     2     0
K2     0     1     2
```

I want to show how many times each unique ID had a hit for each sequence.

```
import pandas as pd

csvFile = 'sequenceFile.csv'

df = pd.read_table(csvFile, sep=',', lineterminator='\n', header=0)
```

So far I have it reading in the file but I have no idea if I should use crosstab or pivot table since I don't want to manipulate the data or calculate anything, just restructure how it appears.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: use `pivot_table` func https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-can-i-pivot-a-dataframe

Comment: `df.pivot(index='ID', columns='Sequence', values='Hits')`

Comment: Same as `pd.crosstab(df['ID'], df['Sequence'], df['Hits'], aggfunc='first')`